# How can I extract a specific substring from one cell using a list of specific values from a different column to return in a new cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a task that I have been taking much longer to complete than I would like to admit.  I don't work in excel often and rarely do any basic coding.  I could really use some help.

What I need to do is extract a code(substring) (using a list of codes I created in column D) from column A and return that code to a new cell (Column B).  If there isn't a code in the cell in column A from the list in Column D, ideally I would like it to return a "DNE" of sorts as a flag.

But right now from some of the source data with valid codes, I'm getting returned codes that are parts of a word of code in column A.

I am close to getting what I want but having particular trouble in cases like in this example below:

[image: Example Table]

Honestly, after failing miserably on my own, I started searching forums and found this snippet that I am using to get me where I am at now.  I have spent hours looking for something that solves my problems but haven't been successful.  I am essentially entering something like this in column B and filling down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$4:$D$10,MATCH(1,COUNTIF($A1,"*"&$D$4:$D$10&"*"),0)),"")
```

So one of the big problems is that its returning codes that are parts of other words or codes from the source.  So for example, the first row of data is returning CE (part of FCE) instead of CMRI. ("FCE" is not a code but "CE" is).  The last row is skipping code FND and returning a portion of CONC as CON

See column C for what I want returned.

I'm sure this is a total hack job so I apologize, I don't often at all work in excel - clearly :D

Again, I really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Sure thing, Im trying to figure out how to post the table here - sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LOOKUP()` function with `FIND()` --> For multiple occurrences this will not work. Infact any look up function cant bring the required output, for multiple occurrences please refer the solutions below.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(FIND(" "&$D$2:$D$7&" "," "&A2&" ")),$D$2:$D$7),"DNE")
```

---

Another alternative way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,$D$2:$D$8,y,TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),
TOROW(FILTER(x,MMULT(N(y=x),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(y),,,0)),"DNE")))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,$D$2:$D$8,
BYROW(A2:A5,LAMBDA(m,
TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(x,MMULT(N(TEXTSPLIT(m," ")=x),
SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(m," ")),,,0)),"DNE")))))
```

---

Using `XMATCH()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),
    ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,$D$2:$D$8)),"DNE")))
```

---

And if you want a single formula then the above formula can be transformed like as below using `BYROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,D2:D8,
BYROW(A2:A5,LAMBDA(m,LET(k,TEXTSPLIT(m,," "),
TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(k,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(k,x)),"DNE"))))))
```

---

Or, you can use this

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,$D$2:$D$8,TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&x&" "," "&A2&" ")),"DNE")))
```

---

Alternative using `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,LET(z,D2:D8,w,TEXTSPLIT(y,," "),
TOROW(FILTER(w,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(w,z)),"DNE")))))),""),1)
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I am having the most luck with your first suggestion using LOOKUP and FIND.  I should have included more sample data but I'm having trouble figuring how to post the spreadsheet here.  For the first row, both CMRI and PVC are codes and I am only getting one output.  Is there a way to output multiple codes from the source (either in the same cell or adjacent column) using the LOOKUP and FIND option?  I tried using one of the other options you so kindly posted but I think the additional codes were added to cells below which I think threw things off down the column.

Comment: Oh yes, hold on. I am updating it, btw may i know what is your excel version?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you!  I think this is what you are looking for? - Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208) 64-bit

Comment: Use this one : `=LET(x,$D$2:$D$8,TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&x&" "," "&A2&" ")),"DNE")))` i have updated in post as well. you can refer

Comment: @DavidGraybill with lookup function it is not possible to return multiple values. even if it does, it will be a more complicated formula. instead use the one shown other than that.

Comment: I am so appreciative of your help!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!  Worked like a charm!  Before using it, I had to remove the numeric characters from the source data and populate a new column to work out a problem where there is a digit at the end of a code in source data (ie. CMRI1) column using =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),0,"")   Is it possible to incorporate something like that in the same formula?  This is truly above and beyond but not necessary!  <3

Comment: So basically I ran the formula you provided on my source data once I removed all the numeric characters from it.  Makes the spreadsheet look a little funny but it still works so please no worries if this adds too much complication.  Thanks again, you rock!

Comment: Hi @DavidGraybill can you post some screen shots with the expected outcome. I understand you have some numeric characters attached to the strings but a screenshot helps to understand more and replicate easily

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Using `XMATCH`

- This will return the first (left-most) occurrence.
- If you need to return multiple occurrences of different matches, use `FILTER` and `TEXTJOIN`.

```
=LET(srg,A2:A5,lrg,D2:D7,
BYROW(srg,LAMBDA(sr,
    IFERROR(INDEX(lrg,TAKE(TOCOL(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(sr," "),lrg),3),1)),"DNE"))))
```

**Edit: Multiple Matches**

```
=LET(srg,A2:A5,lrg,C2:C7,sDel," ",lDel,", ",nm,"DNE",
BYROW(srg,LAMBDA(sr,
    TEXTJOIN(lDel,,IFERROR(INDEX(lrg,
        TOROW(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(sr,sDel),lrg),3)),nm)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for offering some help!  I see what you mean about this returning only the left-most occurrence.  I do need to return multiple occurrences in some cases (very few) - just not sure how to incorporate the FILTER and TEXTJOIN functions.  Additionally, There are some codes that are present in my code list and the source data but returning DNE when the majority are working properly.  Im stumped on this.  Im trying to figure out how to post a little more sample data here also